# Simplifying Fractional Exponents and Can You Explain WHY

Tags: fractions

How do you solve questions like $2^{1/2}$ and can you explain how this works?

Comment: "$2^{1\over 2}$" isn't a question ...

Comment: What Noah said, but the bigger nitpick here is that expressions can't be solved, only simplified.  $2^{1/2}$ can't be simplified any further, but it can be rewritten as $\sqrt 2$.  Is there a specific problem you're working on that you need help with?  It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, I am in grade 6 and learning algebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that

> x^a × x^b = x^(a+b)

From that, try to input a = b = 0.5
, we get

(x^0.5)×(x^0.5)=x^(0.5+0.5)=x^1=x

(x^0.5)^2=x

By taking the square root of both sides, we obtain

x^0.5= \sqrt{x}

Note that we only take the positive value for the answer.

Comment: This is a good answer and i kind of understand.

Comment: I am really glad to hear that. Sorry if i didnt manage to make it looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have the general problem of $x^{a\over b}$ you can always rewrite this as ${(\sqrt[b] x)^a}$. Just to be clear the b is the bth root not multiplication.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.